# Finding the area of a shaded region given a unit square and diagonals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

[image]

I am having trouble finding the area of triangle AEM (E being the intersection of BM and AC). I understand that triangles ACM and ABM both have areas of 0.25. How can I isolate for AEM?

Answer (score 1):

Let $BM\cap AC=\{N\}$.

Thus, $\Delta ANM\sim\Delta CNB$, which says
$$\frac{CN}{NA}=\frac{BC}{AM}=2.$$
Hence, $$S_{\Delta ABN}=\frac{1}{3}S_{\Delta ABC}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{6}.$$

But $$S_{\Delta CNM}=S_{\Delta AMC}-S_{\Delta AMN}=S_{\Delta AMB}-S_{\Delta AMN}=S_{\Delta ABN},$$
which gives $$S_{\Delta ABN}+S_{\Delta CNM}=2\cdot\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{3}.$$
Done!

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to put A at the origin, C at $(1,1)$ and find the intersection point of AC and BM.  You can then compute the area of the two shaded triangles.